# Why isn't my email function working in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, gmail, incoming-mail

This mail function is not working.

In the code below, the `$tomail` and `$frommail` parameters are correct, but the mail isn't getting to my Gmail account.

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->from($from);
$this->email->cc($cc);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
if ( ! $this->email->send())
{
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Comment: what is not working? what is the error? what have you tried?

Comment: no error displaying. $to,$from all are reach correctly

Comment: are you running it on localhost? you have an SMTP set up?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$this->load->library('email');
 $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
 $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
 $this->email->initialize($config);  
 $this->email->from('yourmailid', 'Admin');
 $this->email->to($email);
 $this->email->subject('hello world');
 $this->email->message($body);

 if($this->email->send()) 
     echo "email send";
```

Comment: i tryed but mail not received

Comment: no error get ?  $this->email->initialize($config);  not receving $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
 $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail'; these two paramere in  initialize function